How do development .net core rest api take byte [] array
I developed an endpoint in .net core that takes parameters from FromBody as a byte array. This endpoint converts the incoming file into an image and saves it in the folder in the file directory.
I know that the byte array value is a file. But this byte array value comes from outside. I want to get this byte array with the endpoint I wrote. So while testing, I tried all kinds of methods from postman. I put debug but it doesn't go to the breakpoint section.
I want to test this endpoint How can I do?
Endpoint:
        [HttpPost("ConvertByteToImageFile")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ConvertByteTomageFile([FromBody] byte[] data)
        {
            //Resime çevirir.
            var imageData = GetDataToImage(data);

            try
            {
               //Convert Image.
                SaveImageToFile(imageData);
                return Ok($"Image saved successfully at");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }

        }

        [NonAction]
        public Image GetDataToImage(byte[] byteData)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new(byteData))
            {
                Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                return image;
            }
          
        }
       
        [NonAction]
        public void SaveImageToFile(Image image)
        {
            try
            {
                var imageFolderPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "CameraFiles");
                var imageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // Benzersiz bir isim oluştur

                // Save image
                var imagePath = Path.Combine(imageFolderPath, imageName);
                image.Save(imagePath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }






Could you please tell me why you want to use the frombody to bind with the byte array? Postman doesn't support raw byte array. If you want to pass byte array to web api, please use fromform with the iformfile .
